# Laravel Carbon [escaped] no funciona

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, date, carbon

estoy en Laravel 5.6 y utilizando Carbon intento obtener esto: **13 texto enero texto 2019**.

Según la documentación de Carbon, se haria: `Carbon::now()->format('d [texto] M [texto] Y');` pero no me esta funcionando, imprime asi: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado:

```
Carbon::now()->format('d [texto] M [texto] Y');
Carbon::now()->format('d \\texto M \\texto Y');
Carbon::now()->format('d texto M texto Y');
```

pero sigo sin poder hacer el [escaped].

Comment: prueba de esta manera y me dices `$date = Carbon::now();
      $dia = $date->formatLocalized('%d');
      $mes = $date->formatLocalized('%B');
      $anio = $date->formatLocalized('%Y');
      return $dia." de ".$mes." del ".$anio;` al final debes obtener `13 de Enero del 2019`

Comment: @shadow por ahor tengo esto como me indicas `$hoy = Carbon::now();
 $hoy = $hoy->format('d').' de '.$hoy->format('F').' del '.$hoy->format('Y');`, funciona pero creo que hacer un escape de format seria la forma mas optima seguire buscando...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar Carbon y sus métodos debes entender primero lo que es:

> Una clase que extiende las capacidades de Datetime y otras clases relacionadas de PHP.

En la documentación de Carbon se explica claramente (en inglés) de donde viene el método format:

> Carbon has all of the functions inherited from the base DateTime class. This approach allows you to access the base functionality such as modify, format or diff.

Una traducción aproximada es: **Carbon cuenta con todas las funciones heredadas de la clase base DateTime, lo cual permite acceder a funcionalidades básicas como modify, format o diff.** En dicho texto en inglés se incluyen los enlaces a la documentación de los 3 métodos mencionados.

Después de leer la documentación y entendiendo que format es una función de PHP y no de Carbon, podemos remitirnos a leer en el sitio web de PHP, en el siguiente enlace: http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php

En dicho enlace se explica de donde vienen los formatos aceptados por esta función:

> **format**
>
> Formato aceptado por date().

Posteriormente revisamos la documentación de los formatos de [date()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) y vemos que

```
// Imprime algo como: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

Sin embargo, si leemos con más calma el siguiente ejemplo, dice:

> Puede prevenir que un carácter reconocido en la cadena de formato sea expandido escapándolo con una barra invertida precedente. Si el carácter con una barra invertida es ya una secuencia especial, necesitará escapar también la barra invertida.
>
> Ejemplo #2 Escapar caracteres en date()
>
> ```
> <?php
> // imprime algo como: Wednesday the 15th
> echo date('l \t\h\e jS');
> ```

En el ejemplo 2 está la respuesta a la pregunta:

1. Para «escapar» una palabra usamos solo una barra oblicua invertida.
2. Si las letras están incluidas en el listado de valores posibles que toma la función para dar formato, entonces será necesario utilizar la barra oblicua en cada una de estas letras.

---

Después de la explicación teórica que sustenta que la documentación sí es correcta, aquí va la solución a la pregunta:

```
now()->format('d \t\ex\t\o M \t\ex\t\o Y');
```

Por si acaso, desde Laravel 5.5 existe el helper `now()` que básicamente hace lo mismo que `Carbon::now()`: https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-now